# How to set focus onto form input

Tags: html, forms, input

How to set focus the focus to a specific form input

```
<? foreach($words as $word): ?>
    <form data-word="<? print $word['Word']['en_words'] ?>">

        <input autofocus type="text"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Check"/>

     </form>
    <? endforeach; ?>
```

[image]

Comment: What's the script that changes the "active" form?

Comment: It's simple slider who change form

Comment: What particular slider are you using?  If it's a good one, there should be an event it fires that you can listen for using javascript.  after that event fires, you can change focus to the first input in the active slide.

Comment: I am sure this is a dupe, but corrected the grammar anyway